# how to catch error code in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

i want to add records to table 'pool' with attribute ID and empName from database employees

## theform.html

```
<FORM NAME ='form2' METHOD ='POST' ACTION ='result.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<B>Board Write</B> <BR>

<INPUT TYPE = Text Name = empID value = 'write ID here'>
<INPUT TYPE = Text Name = empName  VALUE = 'write name here'><P>
<INPUT TYPE = 'Submit' Name = Submit2  VALUE = 'Post'>

</FORM>
```

## result.php

```
<?PHP

      $ID = $_POST['empID'];
      $NAME = "'" . $_POST['empName'] . "'";

       $server = "127.0.0.1"; //connect to server
       $user_name = "root";   
       $password = "";

       $database = "employees";


    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);


if($db_found){// there is a database

$tableSQL = "INSERT INTO pool(ID, empName) VALUES " . "(" . $ID . "," . $NAME . ")";


$result = mysql_query($tableSQL);

    if($result){
            print "success!";
    }
    else{
            print "fail!";
        }


}

   mysql_close($db_handle);  //close the connection;



?>
```

in the database, ID is unique and also an INT datatype, i want to catch the error code where the user inputs an ID value that already existing in the database. how do we do this?

Comment: First of all you should prevent getting any errors, e.g. by [protecting your script against SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php). Then you should [take a look into the manual for the mysql functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php).

Comment: What is `$id`? Why user specifies it?

Comment: You can use [`mysql_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to retrieve the error message in case `$result === false`. Note that your database code is horribly unsafe and allows SQL injection.

Comment: Create a password for the root user! And do not connect to the db as root!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mysql_errno()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php) (or [`mysqli_errno()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php), if you use `mysqli`) to get the error number after a query if it failed (check the return value of [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)). It should be error `#1022` (`ER_DUP_KEY`) according to the [mysql error documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_key)

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is better to prevent SQL errors than to catch them. For example, check whether a duplicate exists before you even try to insert the record.

To avoid the issue altogether, you could use an `auto-increment` field for the ID, and allow the database to assign new numbers automatically. Then the user would never need to enter it, so there would never be a clash due to duplicates.

If you do still need to check for errors, then you can use the [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) or [`mysql_errno()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php) functions to get the error details.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // returns true if duplicated
function duplicate_catch_error ($database_connection) {
    $mysql_error = array (1022 => "Can't write; duplicate key in table '%s'",1062 => "Duplicate entry '%s' for key %d", 1586 => "Duplicate entry '%s' for key '%s'");  // also allows for the use of sscanf
    if (array_key_exists(mysql_error($database_connection),$mysql_error)) // checks if error is in array
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

hope this answers your question, also mysql is now depreciated. Use mysqli if you didn't already know
:)